# Phone Direction Detection

Tags: mobile-phone, gps, motion-detection

I know that for a gyroscope, you can detect pitch, roll, and yaw, but how does a phone (or other machine) know what direction the phone is facing (north, east, south, west)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of smartphones include a *compass sensor*; a sensor which responds to Magnetic North.

Through this the phone can tell exactly which direction you're facing, and can use this data, combined with the accelerometer & gyroscope, to help GPS applications with location 'fixing'.

Answer (score 0):

It has a compass built in, in addition to the GPS/accelerometer/gyroscope chips.

For an example, I think the iPhone 6 uses the [AK8963](http://www.akm.com/akm/en/file/datasheet/AK8963.pdf)